# Pandas: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only using as asfreq

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data, fillna

I have the following code and it give me very strange error, my goal is to back fill the missing value for the data with different label. The error happens at this line     `df_filled[is_filled]` if I change the `df_filled=df.asfreq(freq='D').fillna(method='bfill', limit=1).dropna(how='all').drop_duplicates(keep='last')` everything works fine but with this using freq=2D, df_filled[is_filled] doesn't have Boolean form.

```
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import random
    ##Generate the Data
    np.random.seed(11) 
    date_today = datetime.now()
    ndays = 15
    df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [date_today + timedelta(days=(abs(np.random.randn(1))*2)[0]*x) for x in range(ndays)], 
                       'test': pd.Series(np.random.randn(ndays)),     'test2':pd.Series(np.random.randn(ndays))})
    df1=pd.DataFrame({'date': [date_today + timedelta(hours=x) for x in range(ndays)], 
                       'test': pd.Series(np.random.randn(ndays)),     'test2':pd.Series(np.random.randn(ndays))})
    df2=pd.DataFrame({'date': [date_today + timedelta(days=x)-timedelta(seconds=100*x) for x in range(ndays)], 
                       'test': pd.Series(np.random.randn(ndays)),     'test2':pd.Series(np.random.randn(ndays))})
    df=df.append(df1)
    df=df.append(df2)
    df = df.set_index('date').sort_index()
    df = df.mask(np.random.random(df.shape) < .7)
    df=df.reset_index()
    df['test']=df['test'].astype(str)
    df['test2']=df['test2'].astype(str)
    df.replace('nan', np.nan, inplace = True)
    ##

    df.set_index(df['date'].dt.date, inplace = True) 

    df = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
    df_filled=df.asfreq(freq='2D').fillna(method='bfill', limit=2).dropna(how='all').drop_duplicates(keep='last')
    df_filled.set_index(df_filled['date'],inplace=True)
    df_filled=df_filled.drop('date',1)
    df.set_index(df['date'],inplace=True)
    df=df.drop('date',1)
    is_filled = (df.isnull() & df_filled.notnull()) | df.notnull() 
    df_filled[is_filled] ## error happens here
    df_filled[is_filled]=df_filled[is_filled].applymap(lambda x: '_2D' if pd.notnull(x)  else np.nan)
```

output:
`ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only`

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: You can fix the issue by using `is_filled = is_filled.fillna(False)` just after `is_filled = (df.isnull() & df_filled.notnull()) | df.notnull()` but I really need to think how to edit the question accordingly or you should narrow it down to that specific part; your code is reproducible but from its complexity I'm not sure how you didn't debug this yourself. Does that give you your intended output?

Comment: @roganjosh Thank you, your solution solved the issue.  The top portion of the code is only to generate the dataset. I am still relatively new to python and still have a hard time to trace error message to root cause of the problem for some cases.

Comment: You're welcome. FWIW, I think you probably have a convoluted method of getting your desired output but I don't have time to investigate it right now; one thing for sure though, there is no penalty for using spaces, so I suggest you use them before and after `=` and `,` etc. See [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), it will really help with comprehension. Don't crush code up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `print(is_filled = (df.isnull() & df_filled.notnull()) | df.notnull())` then you will see that you have a mixture of `True` and `NaN`. So the solution is to replace the `NaN` values with `False`:

The bottom snippet of code:

```
df=df.drop('date',1)
is_filled = (df.isnull() & df_filled.notnull()) | df.notnull() 
is_filled = is_filled.fillna(False) # Fix here
df_filled[is_filled]=df_filled[is_filled].applymap(lambda x: '_2D' if pd.notnull(x)  else np.nan)
```